# React Native's similar to React's .map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

In React when looping through objects inside an array from props I have used `.map`. This does not seem to be working in React Native. Maybe I am writing it wrong?

React Native Props:

```
var appObject = {
    users:[
        {name:'Jack'},
        {name:'Jill'}
    ]
}
```

In Component React Native:

```
render(){
    this.props.passProps.users.map(function (user, i){
        console.log('user: ',user.userName,'i',i);
        return (
            <Text key={i}>{user.userName}</Text>
        );
    });
}
```

passProps comes from calling this component in the parent component `<UsersAdded passProps={this.props}/>`

The `console.log` logs both user names and the index number. But then I get an error from the parent component saying `A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.` However, take out the .map function and putting in a simple `<Text>Test</Text>` renders correctly.

What is the approach in React Native?

Comment: return this.props.passProps.users.map(function (user, i). Put 'return' key word. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should correct:

1. Forgotten `return` statement in the `render` method
2. Render should not return an array of element. Encapsulate the mapped array into one single `<View />` element which will be returned.